# Add FadeIn to Stylesheet Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this stylesheet toggle script and can't quite figure out where to add a fadeIn to the function / click bind. I've tried adding within the bind and after but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code below reflects what I have now, it's working great sans-fade

**JS**

```
    $.stylesheetInit();
    $(function() {
        $('#toggler').bind('click', function(e) {
            $.stylesheetToggle();
            return false;
        });
        $('.styleswitch').bind('click', function(e) {
            $.stylesheetSwitch(this.getAttribute('rel'));
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And here is what it is calling from a linked JS: [StylesheetToggle](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/stylesheetToggle.js)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly?

The **[styleswitch script](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/2006/05/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery/trackback/)** was created to enable a visitor to dynamically switch the site's css stylesheet, while viewing your website. The script also stores their stylesheet selection in a cookie.

When the stylesheet is changed, the new stylesheet is applied to your entire page. The new stylesheet might apply different sizes, positioning, and display properties to all your elements, so the browser will have to redraw it all, at once.

"Fading" effects are usually applied to a single element, or a group of elements, on a page - not the entire page itself. When you "fadeOut" an element with jQuery, its opacity property is gradually changed to '0' (fully transparent). When you "fadeIn", its opacity is increased so that it's made visible again. jQuery has built-in 'fadeIn', 'fadeOut' and 'fadeToggle' functions, which you can use to easily toggle the visibility of elements on your page with a gradual transition.

To find out more about the `fade` animations in jQuery, you can have a look directly in the jQuery documentation, which has some useful examples:

jQuery fadeToggle: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

jQuery fadeIn: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

jQuery fadeOut: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

In general, it doesn't really make sense to apply `fade` transitions to every element on your page, or to the 'body'. If you want to hide the entire page, apply a new stylesheet, and then show the page with the new styles, it may be easier to use an "overlay" element: an element that covers the entire page (position: fixed, top: 0, left: 0, width: 100vw, height: 100vh), which you can 'fadeIn' to cover the page, then apply the new stylesheet using the script above, then 'fadeOut' to show the new page.

This could be accomplished using custom jQuery animations and callbacks - which are built using the `animate` function:

jQuery animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks -- maybe fade is not the exact solution -- I was trying to figure out a way to make the transition to be less abrupt, like a CSS easing effect, easing from one Stylesheet to the other. The overlay suggestions is good, not exactly what I'd like to achieve, but could work.